# Accessing Oracle object PL/SQL from Java 1.8

Tags: java, object, struct, types, oracle11g

I want to exchange information with a PL/SQL procedure database Oracle 11g using a object of DB.Basically I want to implement something very similar at this example

http://www.journaldev.com/2502/callablestatement-in-java-example

We implemented the part “CallableStatement Example – Oracle DB Object and STRUCT” of the post.

We are using a database Oracle 11g, jdbc diver ojdbc6-11.2.0.3.jar y JDK 1.8.0_45.

When we execute the example a new row is created on the table. But, the problem is varchar field only store “”. Values are missed. We send information on these fields from Java and in the database always store “”.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HD33j.jpg)

Please, could you say me if there is any problem with this version of the driver or with this version of the JDK?

A lot of thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JDBC Thin Oracle 11g](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321253/jdbc-thin-oracle-11g)

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer on stakoverflow

[JDBC Thin Oracle 11g](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321253/jdbc-thin-oracle-11g)

Adding the driver orai18n.jar the problem with string changed to "????" disappeared.

A lot of thnaks.

Comment: The right way to deal with another question fully answering your own is to mark your question as a duplicate of it.